# How can I speed up PgAdmin III Queries?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I've been noticing that PgAdmin III isn't as responsive as I expected it to be.

For instance a query to `select * ...` from a table containing 20,397 rows takes `19.531 seconds` in PgAdmin III and `7.383 seconds` in DbVisualizer 9.0.7. I initially thought this was a coincidence, but it has been consistent across all queries run.

As such it appears that PgAdmin III takes approximately twice as long to query my database over DbVisualizer. So how can I speed up PgAdmin III Queries?

I am using Heroku Postgres 9.1.9 on the Crane package and PgAdmin 1.16.0.

--EDIT--

I upgraded PgAdmin to version 1.16.1 and query time is `19.038 seconds`, so no change with software revision.

Comment: You didn't think the *version of pgAdmin* might be of interest?

Comment: I posted the version. Please see edit.

Comment: Have you tried to compare the time needed with that of `psql`?  I think this difference is a result of _displaying_ the results, over which the user has no real influence...

Comment: @dezso psql gives me `ERROR: character 0xefbfbd of encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in "WIN1252"` so unfortunately I don't have data from psql. However your displaying comment makes sense. I will do some additional testing on a linux machine to see if there is any difference.

Comment: @dezso psql run via Ubuntu 12.04 with \timing shows execution time of 1895.867 ms, where pgAdmin on the same machine takes 21502 ms. Looks like the client is the issue. If you add this as an answer I'll gladly accept. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you see a difference between the clients you use.

In my experience the different PostgreSQL clients need very different times for *displaying* the data they got from the server.  Far the fastest was `psql` and then pgAdminIII, EMS SQL Manager and phppgadmin in who-remembers-what order.

When tried with commands which return no or few rows, the difference is usually negligible or at least very small.  Furthermore, you should see the same actual time consumed (with the usual small differences) when you issue an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE ...` command instead of the actual query which returns the data much slower in one client than the other.